# Cronjob send notification

Tags: centos5, cron

I'm working with `crontab` and have generated some tasks that work fine. However, is there a way to keep the `crontab` notification in a specific file? I'm presently sending the notification to my email - but I need this notification on a local file on my Linux sever.

Here's my `crontab`:

```
MAILTO= verofairy@hotmail.com
HOME=/var/miuser/bin

30 * * * * rm mapVero

0 * * * * ./dspace import -a -e user@domain.user -c 123456789/0001 -s /home/PRUEBA -m mapVero
```

Also, the output of the command `./dspace` is sent successfully to my email.

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet which you're using to send notification to email?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
0 * * * * ./dspace option1 option2 ... > /tmp/dspace.log 2>&1
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

- `2>&1` means that redirects stderr to stdout
- `> /tmp/dspace.log 2>&1`: insert both stdout and stderr to the file
  `dspace.log` (use `>> /tmp/dspace.log` if you want to append)

Comment: This answer it way better than mine so I would recommend this one over what I have stated.

Comment: Depending on the output, you might also use logger to send it to the local syslog. i.e.
0 * * * * ./dspace option1 option2 ... | logger -t 'dspace job'

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a [redirect operator](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles2/042.html) to output what you are after to a file on the server.

Hope this helps

Comment: Excuse me... but I'm really newbie on Linux, can you help me with an example...??

Comment: Here is a simple example, on your Linux prompt type ls > list.txt.  What this will do is take the output of the LS command and put it into a txt file.  So if you have a read though the page I linked it will go into more details on what you can do.

Comment: To make things a bit easier for you you could try something like this  0 * * * * ./dspace import -a -e user@domain.user -c 123456789/0001 -s /home/PRUEBA -m mapVero > /home/<youruser>/log.txt.